# Alternate basis for a subspace of $\mathcal P_3(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I know that two bases $V_1,V_2$ span the same vector space if and only if every vector every vector in $V_1$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in $V_2$, and the other way around. For example, $ \{(1,0),(0,1)\} $ and $ \{(2,0),(0,3)\} $ are both bases of $\mathbb R^2$ because $(1,0)$ can be written as $\frac{1}{2}\cdot(2,0)$, $(0,3)$ can be written as $3\cdot(0,1)$ etc.

In my book, the basis $ \{ 1,(x-5)^2,(x-5)^3 \} $ is used as a basis of the subspace $U$ of $\mathcal P_3(\mathbb R)$ defined by $ U = \{ p \in P_3(\mathbb R): p'(5) = 0 \} $. Now, I'd like to know if the following is a correct basis too: $ \{ 1,(x-6)^2,(x-6)^3 \}$.

I know we can, for example, write $(x-6)^2$ as a linear combination of $(x-5)^2$: 
\begin{array}{rrl}
& (x-6)^2 &= u \cdot 1 + v \cdot (x-5)^2 + w \cdot (x-5)^3 \\
\iff& x^2 - 12x + 36 &= u + x^2 - 10x + 25 \text{ (if we take } v=1,w=0) \\
\iff& u &= -2x+11
\end{array}
I'm wondering if this is mathematically correct (using variables as the scalars for the linear combination) or if I simply don't understand the polynomial vector space well enough. In the latter case, please help me understand it.

Comment: If you want to show that $(x-6)^2$ is a linear combination of $1,(x-5)^2,(x-5)^3$ then $u,v,w$ should be elements in the coefficient field $\mathbb R.$

Comment: This is not correct; $u, v, w$ are scalars, which means they are (constant) real numbers which can't depend on $x$. The problem here is that neither $(x - 6)^2$ nor $(x - 6)^3$ are elements of $U$ at all; they don't satisfy $p'(5) = 0$. So they can't be written as linear combinations of $1, (x - 5)^2$, and $(x - 5)^3$. What is true is that $\{ 1, (x - 6)^2, (x - 6)^3 \}$ is a basis of a different subspace, namely $\{ p \in P_3 : p'(6) = 0 \}$.

Comment: This attempt is destined to fail because $(x-6)^2$ and $(x-6)^3$ don't even belong to $U$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan but if you fill in '5' in the $x$, you obtain $(5-6)^2 = 1$ and $(5-6)^3 = -1$, which, after differentiation, both give $0$, right? So why is this not in $U$?

Comment: @Surzilla: you’re doing the operations in the wrong order. You need to first differentiate then plug in $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, let $V$ be a vector space over field $K,$ and $e_1,\cdots,e_n,v\in v,$ then $v$ is said to be a **linear combination** of $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ iff
$$\exists \ \lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n\in K,\ s.t. \ \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_ie_i=v.$$
In your case, if you want to show that $(x-6)^2$ is the linear combination of $1,(x-5)^2,(x-5)^3,$ them you have to find $u,v,w\in \mathbb R,$ such that $(x-6)^2=u\cdot 1+v\cdot (x-5)^2+w\cdot (x-5)^3.$

However, under the assumption of the existence of such $u,v,w\in \mathbb R,$ you have obtained that $u=-2x+11,$ which is contradiction with  $u\in \mathbb R.$ So the previous assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Why is this a contradiction? $x$ is in $\mathbb R$, so why isn't $-2x+11$?

Comment: $x$ is an element of $\mathcal P_3(\mathbb R),$ i.e. $x$ is a polynomial, not a real number.

Comment: The standard basis of $\mathcal P_n(\mathbb R)$ is $ \{ 
1,x,...,x^n \} $ right? Are you saying that these $x_j$ can't be seen as real numbers? I thought only the linear combinations of these qualified as polynomials.

Comment: Yeah, strictly speaking, real number and polynomial are two completely different concepts, and the “$1$” in the $\left\{1,x,\cdots,x^n\right\}$ is just a symbol of the $unit$ of the vector space $\mathcal P_3(\mathbb R).$

Comment: Ok, thank you! Could you just clear one more thing up? Why are $(x-6)^2$ and $(x-6)^3$ not in $U$, like user8734617 said? If you fill in 5 in the '$x$' and then differentiate, you get 0, which is the requirement of $U$, right?

Comment: In fact the derivative of function  $f(x)=(x-6)^2$ is $f'(x)=2(x-6),$ so we have $f'(5)=-2.$ I think you have made a mistake in the order of calculation.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. :)